# How to integrate React-Select with Rest API(Remote Data)

Tags: rest, material-ui, react-select

I'm very new to `ReactJS`, I'm trying to create a component with a list of values(should be fetched from an API) and should allow the search.

https://codesandbox.io/s/v1v1xp1xn3

Above example is working fine, but it uses local data. How to integrate with remote data. Upon every key press, it should hit API and fetch new data.

Comment: Did you read the async react-select documentation https://react-select.com/async ?

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is the React-Select [`AsyncSelect`](https://react-select.com/async), as @Laura stated. The documentation is a little confusing. Here's the base example in the docs:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/lib/Async';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

const filterColors = (inputValue: string) => {
  return colourOptions.filter(i =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  );
};

const promiseOptions = inputValue =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(filterColors(inputValue));
    }, 1000);
  });

export default class WithPromises extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={promiseOptions} />
    );
  }
}
```

You'll see here that the `loadOptions` took a `promiseOptions` method that returned a Promise that eventually resolved to a list of options. If you replace the internals of that method with a `fetch()` (which returns a Promise), then when that request resolved to the list of options, those options would then be applied to the `AsyncSelect`.

```js
const promiseOptions = inputValue => {
  const url = `my/remote/source${inputValue ? '?searchParam=' + inputValue : ''}`;
  return fetch(url)
           .then(response => response.json()) // my option list array?
           .catch(err => {
             console.log('some error', err);
           });
};
```